# Populate var with value from dropdown

Tags: javascript

Currently I have a script that when a user selects an item from 4 different dropdowns with the same class it populates an input field with the values.

```
$('.neigh').on('change',function() {

            selectedItems = new Array();
            //console.log(selectedItems);
            $(".neigh option[value]:selected").each(function() {
                if($.inArray($(this).val(), selectedItems) != 0){
                  selectedItems.push($(this).val());
                }
            });
            //console.log(selectedItems);
                var data = selectedItems.join(',');
            $(".hood").val(data);
        });
```

I would like to modify this so that instead of it appending the value with a ',' to completely empty the array and add the new value. How would I go about doing that to this current script?

EDIT:

So the result would be if user chose option 1 and then option 2. Option 2 will only be within data.

EDIT 2:

There are 4 dropdowns with multiple options. Each dropdown is linked by the same class to this function. Previously it appended each choice to one input box. So if a user selected mutliple options the hidden input box would contain "24, 24, 6, 7" etc. Instead of this I would rather just the most recent selection. So if a user selects 24 the value in the hidden input would be 24, but if they select another option in a different dropdown it will now contain the new value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.neigh').on('change',function() {
            $(".neigh option[value]:selected").each(function() {
                $(".hood").val($(this).val());
            });          
        });
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, but I would like 'data' to have just one value at a time, also updated the question.

Comment: @shayward I updated again, ... there is no need to use an Array if you're only storing one value then emptying. Changed to string.

Comment: Hmm, for some reason it does not populate the .hood field at all. I also removed the s from the selectedItems) != 0 as it caused an issue prior.

Comment: @shayward You would want to change the entire logic since it won't be using an array. I updated that line to show you what I mean. However, since you're not needing an array, I don't see the purpose of even keeping that line at all.

Comment: There was an extra ')' but still not functioning

Comment: @shayward could you explain in plain english what you want the function to do then? I think the problem is I simply don't understand the issue.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27352/discussion-between-evan-and-shayward)